# Rails5 error: No methoderror in ProjectsController#new. I defined it but

Tags: ruby, methods, ruby-on-rails-5

i am getting "undefined method 'new' for Project:Module

My projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
    @project = Project.new(project_param)
    if @project.save
     redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def project_param
        params.require(:projects).permit(:name, :description)
    end
```

end

my routes

Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pages#home
       about GET    /about(.:format)             pages#about
        help GET    /help(.:format)              pages#help
    projects GET    /projects(.:format)          projects#index
             POST   /projects(.:format)          projects#create
 new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
     project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
             PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FseQ6.png)

Comment: I'm willing to bet the stacktrace sees your controller but doesn't know what to do with `@project = Project.new`.  Sounds like you have both a module and a class named `Project`.

Comment: Yes, i do have both named "Project", should i change one or rename the app? I was following along with an instructor as i try to learn.

Comment: Can you add a repository?

Comment: https://github.com/quietwar/CohortProjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change the params to "params.require(:project)" using the singular instead of the plural.